# Verb agreement for "Capturing one knight or three pawns"

Tags: grammatical-number

> In a game of chess, capturing one knight or three pawns **yields/yield** the same result

What should be the answer — *yields* or *yield*? The rule says if one of the items joined by "or" is singular and the other plural, the verb becomes of the subject which is after "or".

The answer according to that should be "yields" but the book says "yield".

Comment: I think the subject is "capturing".

Comment: No, the subject is not _capturing_. That's the gerund in the complement clause _capturing one knight or three pawns_, which is the subject of _yields_, singular. Clauses and prepositional phrases are automatically singular. Language is not a matter of stringing words together like beads on a string; it's more like atoms, molecules, cells, and organs in a body -- there are intermediate structures, usually called Constituents, that do most of the work. Constituents are what syntax is all about.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a technical term not part of standard English usage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "capturing" is the subject of the clause, and it's singular. So the correct form of the verb is "yields".

Comment: Not according to Professor Lawler.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler writes in a comment that the subject is a constituent, not the single word *capturing*:

No, the subject is not capturing. That's the gerund in the complement clause capturing one knight or three pawns, which is the subject of yields, singular. Clauses and prepositional phrases are automatically singular. Language is not a matter of stringing words together like beads on a string; it's more like atoms, molecules, cells, and organs in a body -- there are intermediate structures, usually called Constituents, that do most of the work. Constituents are what syntax is all about. – John Lawler

Comment: So then what should be the verb form plural/singular i.e. yields or yield? The book says the answer should be 'yield'.

Comment: '[The complement clause] is the subject of **yields**, sin....'

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two things: "capturing one knight" and "capturing three pawns". You say that these two hypothetical actions yield the same result. So you need to put "and" between them, and use the plural verb "yield". It might be easier to see what's going on if we use A and B instead of the phrases which describe these actions. So it's

1. A and B yield the same result.

If you use "or" rather than "and", then the subject becomes singular. In that case, to make the sentence grammatical, the verb would have to be singular:

2. A or B yields the same result.

But that raises the question "the same result as what?". The sentence says that one thing yields the same result. This is nonsense, because "the same" implies that two or more things are the same as each other.

So the correct way to say what you mean is a sentence which is like 1., that is,

Capturing a knight **and** capturing three pawns **yield** the same result.

---

I acknowledge that there are some contexts in which a singular verb is correct. But then such a context would have to include notions which aren't in the original question. For example:

Capturing Black's bishop would give White an advantage. Capturing Black's knight or three Black pawns would yield the same result.

Here, "the same result" means "the same result as capturing Black's bishop would give".